# Where is MapView in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-mapview

I cannot find mapview in Android Studio palette.  I am using the new Android Studio and it seems silly but I cannot find this.  I looked through the development site but it seems mapview does still exist.
Is there something I am missing?

I aslo tried to just add it in the XML and it says the the mapview class is not found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Android Studio (as well as in IntelliJ) there is no `MapView` in palette. If you need to use Maps in your layout, declare it with:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

[Google Maps Android API v2 documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/)

[There](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html) you have a nice reference how to use maps v2.

We used `MapView` in Android Maps v1, but now it is deprecated ([reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview)). So this is the reason why there is no `MapView` in Android Studio palette.